# Create DLL file in VB.NET and use in Excel VBA

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, dll

I have created a DLL file in VB.NET and I want use it in Excel VBA. When I use it like a function it is working perfect but when I use sub with a `ByRef` variable it does not work and Excel restarts with an error.

The code in VB.NET is:

```
Public Function distinctArr(ByVal arr As String()) As String()
        Return arr.ToList.Distinct.ToArray
End Function

Public Sub sortArr(ByVal arr As String(), ByRef a As String())
    Dim tolist As List(Of String) = arr.ToList
    tolist.Sort()
    a = tolist.ToArray
End Sub
```

This is the code in VBA:

```
Dim objMda As Excelcode.mda
Set objMda = New Excelcode.mda
Dim distinc_Item() As String
Dim all_Items() As String
all_Items = rng_to_string(rng_rizmetre)
distinc_Item = objMda.distinctArr(all_Items) '''This line is working perfect
Dim Sorted_Item() As String
objMda.sortArr distinc_Item, Sorted_Item
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: What is the error? "does not work" doesn't mean anything. Did you reference the type library in VBA? Where and how is `objMda` declared and assigned? Does the VB.NET code have the required type and member attributes? Do you see your VB.NET API in VBA's object browser? Have you tried passing the arrays `As Object` and `ByRef`? Is your VB.NET code catching any exception? Have you tried debugging the VB.NET code by attaching to the EXCEL.EXE process? Do you know that you could use `System.Collections.ArrayList` directly in VBA for this?

Comment: the error is "Microsoft Excel stop working"...when i use fuction widout any byref variable in the library the library is working perfect but when i use byref variable in library Excel stop working and restart excel.

Comment: "Microsoft Excel stopped working" is because your DLL is throwing an exception without catching it. You need to attach the VS debugger to the running EXCEL.EXE process and see what the exception is. Consider exposing a `Function` instead of returning your result with a `ByRef` parameter.

Comment: i know that when i use function without byref variable the dll works.but i need a sub that return several variable and for this purpose i must use byref variable

Comment: You realize that makes a shitty API? Your sorting method has one single return value. A method that returns one single return value should be implemented as a `Function` that *returns* that value - that's how idiomatic VBA/VB/.NET code is written. Your method doesn't return "several variables", so there's nothing in what you have here that justifies abusing `ByRef` like this. Declare `Sorted_Item` as a `Variant` and make the VB.NET code take a `ByRef outResult As Object` if you absolutely want that. Just saying, it's ugly code. Yours is probably failing because `Sorted_Item` isn't initialized.

Comment: VBA talking to .NET happens through COM interop; your VBA array needs to be marshaled before VB.NET can use it. Again, **use a debugger attached to your process** to find out what the exact exception is, we can't do that for you.

Comment: Also your `Function` is inefficient, it's iterating the array more than it needs to. Remove the `ToList` call to `Return arr.Distinct.ToArray` instead, you'll have the same result, pretty much twice as fast.

Comment: BTW, no need to convert it to list. just `Return arr.Distinct.ToArray` and `a = arr.ToArray : Array.Sort(a)`

Comment: the dll file works in vb.net.i create a project in vb.net and reference dll file and works perfect.but dll doesn't work in excel

Comment: Yes, we got that part. You need to debug your VB.NET dll *when it is used through VBA*. To do that you need to attach the VB.NET / Visual Studio debugger to the running EXCEL.EXE process, place a breakpoint on the first executable statement, execute the failing VBA code (which calls your dll), and then you can step through the VB.NET code and inspect what VBA has been giving you. The VB.NET code is throwing an exception, and without knowing what that exception is, you're working blindly.

Comment: It is strange that you state that passing an array from VBA to .Net as `ByVal` works.  Typically, this results in the VBA compiler error:  _Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic_, with the resolution being to declare the argument as `ByRef` (see: [BUG: Visual Basic 6.0 cannot use the .NET method with the ParamArray parameter in Visual Studio .NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20140531181434/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/327084)).

Comment: I attached debugger to EXCEL.EXE and error was this "Exception thrown at 0x70731138 (clr.dll) in EXCEL.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000002.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i can find my answer.
code in vb.net

```
Public Class MainClass
    Sub sortArr(ByVal arr As String(), ByRef sortedarr As String())
        sortedarr = arr
        Array.Sort(sortedarr)

    End Sub
End Class
```

and code in excel vba:

```
Sub aaa()
Dim Mycode As excelcode.MainClass
Set Mycode = New excelcode.MainClass
Dim arr(2) As String
arr(0) = "m"
arr(1) = "a"
arr(2) = "d"
Dim sortedArr() As String
ReDim sortedArr(0)
  Mycode.sortArr arr, sortedArr
End Sub
```

by this code i can pass array byval to vb.net dll then vb.net pass sorted array.